# Comparison of fabric bluing and blue glaciers

Tags: optics

In learning about the effects of fabric bluing (it seems to mask yellowed fabric using a small amount of blue dye) I've wondered how this compares with the also-perceived blue of glaciers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are different phenomena. The blue from glaciers is due to scattering of light and absorption. The longer wavelengths reds are absorbed while the blue light not absorbed as much continues to scatter forward.

For the fabric the blueing has a small amount of blue dye and is a complementary color for yellow. So if you have a fabric that is old or yellowed due to the blue portion of the spectrum is being absorbed having a small amount of blue dye added increases the amount of blue light reflected so this helps the fabric appear white to the eye again.